SPN not replicated between different AD forests
I have issues with a SPN, which is not known by a domain controller.
What I want to achieve:
I have a fileshare, which should be available via FQDN lansweeper.example.com.
lansweeper.example.com is an A record, for the IP address of the server vm1.servers.com (I cannot change that to a CNAME, unfortunately).
I added the SPN cifs/lansweeper.example.com to the SPNs of the computer account. The computer account is in forest finance.cc
The user trying to connect to the fileshare is in the forest vienna.cc. When we try to connect to the fileshare using lansweeper.example.com, kerberos authentication fails with error-code: eRR-S-PRINCIPAL-UNKNOWN (7). I verified the client made a TGS Request for cifs/lansweeper.example.com.
There is a full trust relationship between these forests.
Based on what I observed, I would assume that the issue is that the Domain Controllers from vienna.cc domain do not know about that SPN. Is there something we have to do, so the DCs knows about the SPN?
I have not found any information on that topic but I am pretty sure it is not just waiting until the information is synced because this fails for more than a week.

As far as I know, individual SPNs don't get replicated between forests – instead it should work like a cross-realm Kerberos trust, i.e. the client's KDC should respond with a cross-realm referral indicating the service's realm (then the client would get a cross-realm TGT for the new realm, and finally get a service ticket directly from the target realm's KDC)... but I have absolutely no idea how and where an AD DC keeps track of trusted realms, so can't begin to write a real answer.

Hi,
thanks for your reply. Gave some good hints. I read about referrals. Reason for my issue is probably that the FQDN ´example.com´ is not an AD domain. So KDC probably does not know to which trusted domain the referral should be made to.
So I will try to use a different FQDN instead, where the FQDN is linked to an AD

That's possible; I believe there is a registry key or a GPO for AD DCs to customize the domain-to-Kerberos-realm mappings somewhere.

[I'm refreshing my memory; it seems that the KDC actually returns the cross-realm TGT as the "referral". That is, you request HTTP/foo@LOCAL but the KDC instead gives you a ticket for "krbtgt/REMOTE@LOCAL", and you're supposed to request HTTP/foo@REMOTE using that new cross-realm TGT. I've mainly worked with this in MIT Krb5 realms; hardly ever in AD though.]

I think part of what you need to add "SPN Suffixes" to the trusting forest.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-msds-spnsuffixes Set-ADForest -SPNSuffixes ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adforest "Modifies the list of service principal name (SPN) suffixes of the forest. This parameter sets the multi-valued msDS-SPNSuffixes property of the cross-reference container" Cross-Reference Container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/c-crossrefcontainer

That totally makes sense. Now I know how to achieve my goal. Thank you guys!
